# Get timezone name from NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Any way to get timezone abbreviation(e.g UTC, EET) from NSDate? I'm getting NSDate from string, e.g 2012-08-26 02:54:50 +0200 and need to show timezone of this date.

Currently doing that:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate *isoDate = [formatter dateFromString: isoTime.value];
NSInteger offset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate: isoDate];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT: offset];
```

But I'm getting GMT+03:00 for timeZone abbreviation, but it should be EET. Any way to get it?

Comment: This may not be possible, because the same offset may correspond to multiple time zone names. For example, `COT` (Colombia time) and `EST` (US Eastern Standard Time) are both GMT-5.

Comment: As Tommy says, you can't get what isn't there.  There's no timezone data in an NSDate.

Comment: (Though you can, of course, separately extract the timezone from the date string you're parsing.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `NSDate` is time zone independent; it doesn't inherently have a time zone. You therefore can't get a time zone from it.

`secondsFromGMTForDate:` returns the offset of that time zone (the default one, in your case) from GMT at the specified date. It's returning information about the `NSTimeZone` which may depend on the date (eg, if your time zone honours daylight savings), not about the date.